# How to re-send failed API requests on internet re-connection using Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors, rxjs-observables

I'm calling some API call on submit, due to internet connection interrupt failed API calls. I need to re-send failed API's on re-connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rxjs retry / retryWhen operator

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retry.html
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html

---

**Edit:**

```
return next.handle(req).pipe(
  retry(/***/),
```

Comment: I can't write retry/retry When on each and every service call . I want this to be handle by interceptor

Comment: Yes you can. You need to pipe the next.handle, I will add it in the answer

Comment: How to define delay or retry attempt's? because, I can't decision making on retry operation. suppose internet connection interrupt and re-connection after long time.so delay or retry will not work.